# Android studio 1.5.1 debug error “Connection refused”. Debug port is busy

Tags: android, android-debug

I'm getting this error continuously, while trying to debug on emulator.

I've tried the following solutions with no success:

1) make sure ports 8600+ are open with with kill .
2) add debuggable true on debug build types.
3) restart Android studio and my mac.
4) Added permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
```

OS:- Yosemite
Android Studio:- 1.5.1
API Used:- 23

### Message on Emulator:-

[image]

### Console trace:-

```
Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is ready: Nexus_5_API_23_x86 [emulator-5554]
Target device: Nexus_5_API_23_x86 [emulator-5554]
Installing APK: /Users/Abhishek/AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/sunshine.messy.com.sunshine
Installing sunshine.messy.com.sunshine
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/sunshine.messy.com.sunshine"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/sunshine.messy.com.sunshine
Success
```

Launching application:

```
sunshine.messy.com.sunshine/sunshine.messy.com.sunshine.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "sunshine.messy.com.sunshine/sunshine.messy.com.sunshine.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Debug port is busy
Debug port is busy
Debug port is busy
Debug port is busy
Debug port is busy
Debug port is busy
Debug port is busy
Debug port is busy
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=sunshine.messy.com.sunshine/.MainActivity }
```

### Logcat trace:-

```
01-30 11:28:43.185 2416-2416/sunshine.messy.com.sunshine I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-30 11:28:43.228 2416-2416/sunshine.messy.com.sunshine W/ActivityThread: Application sunshine.messy.com.sunshine is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-30 11:28:43.233 2416-2416/sunshine.messy.com.sunshine I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
```

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this issue, I realised that I had recently changed the Computer Name of my Mac.

Having changed the Computer Name back to what it was (System Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer Name), I can now debug apps through Android Studio again.